# Convert a very large base n number to bytes

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, integer-overflow, pow

I have a very large number in base `n` (`n` is specified by user), stored as an array with each element representing a digit. `u[0]` is the highest digit, `u[1]` is the second highest, `u[-1]` is the lowest digit and so on. Leading zeros are understood to be meaningless: For instance, if `n` is 8, `[0, 0, 0, 4, 7, 3]` is equivalent to `[4, 7, 3]` and both equal (473) in base 8, or 315 in base 10, or `13B` in hex, or `[1, 59]` as a byte array.

I want to convert this into an array of bytes which correspond to base-256 representation of the same number, with minimal leading zeros. I have the following code to do so:

```
def base_n_to_byte_array(digits, from_base):
    """ Converts a base n number to a byte array.

    :param digits: Digits of the number, starting from highest.
    :param from_base: Base in which the number is given.
    """

    x = 0
    n = len(digits)
    for i in range(0, len(digits)):
        x += digits[i] * int(math.pow(from_base, n - i - 1))

    min_length = max(math.ceil(math.log(x, 256)), 1)
    byte_array = x.to_bytes(min_length, byteorder='big')
    return byte_array
```

This works for smaller numbers (a few hundred digits). However, it turns out that `math.pow` is pretty limited, for instance if we use base 8, `math.pow(8, 341)` is the highest power I can get, and `math.pow(8,342)` fails with `OverflowError: math range error`.

I know that the common way of dealing with large numbers is to represent them as floating points - but in this case I am using this code to encode/decode binary files into alternative representations (eg. trytes). Therefore, if due to loss of precision the less significant bytes are altered, a lot of the data will be corrupted, so I can't use an approximate power calculation - I need the result to be exact.

How can I solve this problem? Is there a version of `math.pow` that doesn't overflow? Is there a more efficient base conversion algorithm that I'm overlooking?

Comment: What you need is [Arbitrary-precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).

Comment: @WhatsUp Python does this automatically, as long as you avoid floats.

Comment: @WhatsUp I know that is one of my options, I am asking how to do it in Python3.

Comment: @Teepeemm Yep, luckily for you Pythoners ...

Comment: If you read the number backwards, then you can iteratively build up the multiplier: `value_of_place *= from_base` instead of `int(math.pow)`.

Comment: Or, even if you read the numbers forwards, you can use another number `y` to store the power of `from_base`. Just multiply it by `from_base` at each step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a version of `math.pow` that doesn't overflow?

Try using the built-in exponentiation operator, `**`. AFAIK it doesn't have the same limitations that `math.pow` does.

```
>>> math.pow(8,342)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: math range error

>>> 8**342
719077253944926363091722076315609893447190791576922629093720324630930703222003852530833909289630144084480455519485573430635159075257666489971389722557896497511071573699461941105208878404984376477812331808340023075352602729369851525895652442163308948653402042738345192959788983753918865219341425318496896548864L
```

Comment: The documentation for [`math.pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.pow) specifically says that `pow` (aka `**`) doesn't have the same limitations.

Comment: Great! In that case I rescind my "AFAIK" and heartily endorse both `pow` and `**`.